# Displaying an alert box of error message using CSS

Tags: html, css

Am creating a login form on a website whereby am having trouble creating an alert box at the top of the form that should display error messages after server-side validation and sanitization of the user input.The problem is that when the page loads, it displays the alert-box, while I want it to display only when displaying error messages. Please assist?

**HTML PART**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="form">

<span class="info">
<?php
        echo
            $fNameErr;
            $lNameErr;
            $emailErr;

?>
</span>


<br>

    <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>


                <form action="signup.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

                    <div class="top-row">
                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <label>
                                <span class="req"></span>
                            </label>
                            <input placeholder="Firstname*" type="text" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>" required autocomplete="off" name='firstname' />
                        </div>

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <label>
                                <span class="req"></span>
                            </label>
                            <input placeholder="LastName*" type="text" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>" required autocomplete="off" name='lastname' />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            <span class="req"></span>
                        </label>
                        <input placeholder="Email Address*" type="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" required autocomplete="off" name='email' />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            <span class="req"></span>
                        </label>
                        <input placeholder="Set A Password*" type="password"required autocomplete="off" name='password'/>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="register">Register</button>

                </form>



</div> <!-- /form -->
 </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

**style.css page**

```
.info {
    color: pink;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #66131c;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span class="info">
<?php
        echo
            $fNameErr;
            $lNameErr;
            $emailErr;

?>
</span>
```

try changing this to the below. let me know how it goes

```
<?php
if(isset($fnameErr) || isset($lNameErr) || isset($emailErr)){
    echo "<span class='info'>";
    echo $fNameErr . $lNameErr . $emailErr;
    echo "</span>"
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if(isset($fnameErr) || isset($lNameErr) || isset($emailErr)){
        echo '<span class="info">';
        echo $fNameErr;
        echo $lNameErr;
        echo $emailErr;
       echo '</span>';
   }
?>
```

try this. If it does not work , show us your php code too

Comment: I think also the `<span class="info">...</span>` needs to be conditionally visible/hidden, now it will display an empty box (if `.info` is styled to be like a box)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you'd only want this to display when those variables have some kind of value and they would otherwise be blank.  It would be pretty easy to only output this HTML element when that is the case.  Perhaps something like this:

```
<?php if(isset($fnameErr) || isset($lNameErr) || isset($emailErr)){
  echo
    "<span class='info'>"
    $fNameErr;
    $lNameErr;
    $emailErr;
    "</span>";
} ?>
```